# How in operator works in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, in-operator

I want to check for multiple string comparison in groovy.
For example:

```
if (cityName in ('AHD','BLR','DEL'))
{

}
```

But, using this way, it is giving syntax error.

Comment: Just similar to `contains`

Answer (score 2):

To define in-place collection use `[]` instead of `()`:

```
if (cityName in ['AHD','BLR','DEL']) {

}
```

Anyway, `in` is used correctly.